# How to calculate data length in each column (in a single table) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

This code provide a possibility to sum a datalength in a single column:

```
    select sum(datalength(column_1))
    from my_table
```

This part provide me an information about columns in my_table

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='my_schema'
```

and now i would like to add a column to second select result with sum of data length for each column, so i nedd a column like this:

```
sum(datalength(col_1))
sum(datalength(col_2))
    .  
    .          
    .
sum(datalength(col_n))
```

Could you help me to prepare a proper select to achieve explained result?

EDIT: I need to count how many megabytes have elements in each column (in all rows):

1) if its int type column it is easy: 
    (size of int * number of rows)

2) when column is a varchar i would like to add size of each varchar in this column

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, you want to `SUM` the `DATALENGTH` of every column and every row in your table?

Comment: so this is dynamic column? for sum1, sum2, sum3

Comment: i add "EDIT" section with better description to make it more visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you want to *" ... add a column to second select result (`SELECT ... FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ...`) with sum of data length for each column ... "*, a dynamic statement should be an option:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''
SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
    @stm,
    N'UNION ALL ',
    N'SELECT ''',
    COLUMN_NAME, 
    N''' AS [COLUMN_NAME], ''',
    TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    N''' AS [TABLE_SCHEMA], ''',
    TABLE_NAME, 
    N''' AS [TABLE_NAME], ',
    CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ORDINAL_POSITION), 
    N' AS [ORDINAL_POSITION], ''',
    DATA_TYPE, 
    N''' AS [DATA_TYPE], ',
    N'(SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(',
    COLUMN_NAME,
    N')) FROM ',
    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA),
    N'.',
    QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME),
    N') AS [DATA_LENGTH] ' 
)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchema'
SELECT @stm = STUFF(@stm, 1, 10, N'')

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is going to result in a lot of scans here (1 per column). Why not do this in 1?

Comment: @Larnu, you are right. I did not consider performance as a factor. I hope this is a single execution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is *this* what you're after?

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Schema sysname = N'dbo', --Replace with appropriate Schema
        @Table sysname = N'PerformanceTest'; --Replace with appropriate Table

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + 
           STUFF((SELECT N' +' + @CRLF +
                         N'       ISNULL(SUM(DATALENGTH(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N')),0)'
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                  WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
                    AND C.TABLE_NAME = @Table
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,11,N'') +N' AS DataLengthTotal' + @CRLF +
          N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + N';';

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Seems the OP is *not* after a grant total, but total by column. This is can be easily be changed by changing the below

```
SELECT N' +' + @CRLF +
       N'       ISNULL(SUM(DATALENGTH(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N')),0)'
```

To the below:

```
SELECT N', ' + @CRLF +
       N'       ISNULL(SUM(DATALENGTH(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N')),0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(C.COLUMN_NAME,N'DataLength'))
```

And removing the alias after the `STUFF` expression.

Comment: Did you spell your table's name incorrectly, @JanekWojciechowski ? The fact that it's returning `NULL`, seems like something else is *wrong* though here. Did you  change something else in my code?

Comment: This works fine for me @JanekWojciechowski [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c2129d8e2c6e1cd3f40ba563f761a6b3)

Comment: I'm *guessing*, @JanekWojciechowski, that you have a column full of `NULL`s? I *assumed* this wouldn't be the case (as having a column completely full of `NULL` seems like a wasted column). you'll need to wrap the `DATALENGTH` with an `ISNULL` (will update anyway). If you have a column full of `NULL`, then `DATALENGTH` returns `NULL` too: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9b15075b76fb893962a1050aa9a45a5c)

Comment: Ok, but still, i receive only one column with null, i need to have a column number the same as in table and sum(datalength(col)) for each column

Comment: This is why answering the comment I made is helpful, @JanekWojciechowski, as I had to guess what you were after. You *should* be able to easily manipulate the above to give you a column for each column, instead of a grant total.

Comment: Thx, below i receive a percfect answer